# Substrate Node wont restart

Tags: error, nodes, block-production, log

We are running a substrate node in testing/development and the server ran out of disk space. We cleared up space by deleting the log files and now the node wont start.

Service(Client(RuntimeApiError(Application(UnknownBlock("State already discarded for 0x6d8fc6...

possible wrote a corrupt block..

is there any resources on this sort of error?

how would you delete that possibly corrupt block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not delete individual blocks from the database that easily. When you have run out of disk space with the node running, it means that you have corrupted the database. The only solution for this is to delete the entire database. We recently added the [`storage-monitor`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/8f9b07445057ab83a057cb61aac56a4a0a671395/client/storage-monitor/src/lib.rs) which needs to be added to your service instantiation and then brings down the node if the server runs out of disc space.

Comment: thank you. So when you say added to your service instantiation. is there docs on this?

Comment: No docs yet. Best is source is the code currently: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/db71f778e6ce7d7e3f11d936d6c46ac6affbbf19/bin/node/cli/src/service.rs#L571-L576

Comment: Cool. thanks. I see that it is part of the cli of substrate but i dont see how to add that to our substrate based node.

Comment: You need to add the crate and then initialize it as shown above.